# AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() returns null in case of google

Tags: google-contacts-api

AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() returns null in case of sign in via google. In case of facebook it works fine> I have enabled

Answer (score 0):

I Upgraded all my OWIN references using NuGet. this should work. Earlier my version was 3.0 when I upgrade to 4.0 it works for me.

Comment: Please don't write answers in a way that makes them look like questions.
There are systems in place to check for Not An Answer (NAA) posts.
This answer was falsely picked up by one of them. Please consider editing it to look more like an answer. Remove the "I have tried many solutions and after spending hours and hours" part.